# How to generate a random date of workdays within a specific month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

enter code hereI'm newbie and I want to generate a day/date in python in order to help my collegues. Here we assume that Sundays and Saturdays are weekends and why my function sometimes returns to a None? I want to pass a fixed year and month everytime I run, for example, just run a=RandomWeekdays(2018,6) to get the day, any solutions?

```
import calendar
import datetime
import random
import re
def RandomWeekdays(year,month):
    def randomdate(year, month):
        dates = calendar.Calendar().itermonthdates(year, month)
        return random.choice([date for date in dates if date.month == month])

    RandomDate_R = randomdate(2018, 6)
    RandomDateStr_R = RandomDate_R.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_num_iter = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}',RandomDateStr_R)
    day = int(date_num_iter[3])
    dayOrder = calendar.weekday(2018,month,day)
    if dayOrder in range(0,5):
        return day
    else:
        day+=2`enter code here`
        if day > 29:
            day-=4
            return day
a=RandomWeekdays(2018,6)
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you first describe in words what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: Did not look clear, but the `None` maybe because `if day>29`, no corresponding `else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get `None` because you haven't handle the corresponding condition with `if`, you can add handle code with write `else` for `if`.

But I recommend you to use pandas to achieve it easily.

```
import random, calendar
import pandas as pd

def randomDate(year, month):
    day_count = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    t = random.choice(pd.date_range(f"{year}-{month}-01", f"{year}-{month}-{day_count}", freq='D'))
    return randomDate() if t.dayofweek == 5 or t.dayofweek == 6 else t

randomDate(2018, 8)
# Timestamp('2018-08-20 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

Comment: It’s quite clear that OP wanted year and month as input so why did you ignore it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I complete it.